# Json stream parser in C# for windows phone

Tags: c#, json, parsing, windows-phone-7, tcp

I am building a wp7 application.I want to parse JSON string coming from a continuous tcp stream.I want a json parser which can parse from a stream.Is there any SAX JSON parser to parse from a stream.I am looking for a tcp stream parser.that is continuous stream is coming from my server.And i want to parse the stream and generate JSON objects on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON.NET library, you can get it here: http://json.codeplex.com/

I state from codeplex these features of JSON.NET

- Flexible JSON serializer for converting between .NET objects and JSON
- LINQ to JSON for manually reading and writing JSON
- High performance, faster than .NET's built-in JSON serializers
- Write indented, easy to read JSON
- Convert JSON to and from XML
- Supports .NET 2, .NET 3.5, .NET 4, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Windows 8.

and here is a little example:

```
public class MyClass
  {
    public string MyProperty;
    public string[] MyArray;        
  }
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new MyClass() { MyProperty = "Test",  MyArray = new string[] { "Test1", "Test2" } });
    //{"MyProperty":"Test","MyArray":["Test1","Test2"]}"
```

**EDIT**

Here is a little example:

```
      System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
      using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
      {      
        byte a = 0;
        var list = new List<byte>();
        do{
          a = (byte)stream.ReadByte();
          list.Add(a);
          if(/*Test if valid JSON string*/)
          {
            var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(list.ToArray());
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(str);
          }
        }while(a != -1)
      }
```

you can use TcpClient to connect. Check this question [Subscribing over TCP, deserializing each recieved JSON line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959653/subscribing-over-tcp-deserializing-each-recieved-json-line)

Comment: I am looking for a tcp stream parser.that is continuous stream is coming from my server.And i want to parse the stream and generated JSON objects on the fly.

Comment: Can't you receive the stream part by part, save it to a string and then deserialize it?

Comment: note that you need all the JSON string to be able to deserialize it, so the only solution is to get the string from the web and then deserialize it

Comment: I am receiving a continuous stream containing several JSON strings.I need to separate them to get the real JSON objects.

Comment: Yeah, thus is exactly my point, you have to seperate by checking for example for special character or sequence, and each time you find the sequence/character you deserialize the string

Comment: Is there any C# implementation for the same.